# Como mostrar cifras decimales en input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Amigos estoy trabajando en una pagina en la cual tengo que mostrar unas cifras en decimales, mas concretamente en millones por ejemplo 1,000,000 algo así es lo que estoy tratando de mostrar ya que desde la base de datos solo me muestra el numero tal cual es 1000000, la idea es agregarle esa separación decimal de miles y millones a mi numero, la forma en como los números en los input text es mediante jquery, no se si exista una expresión regular que me permita hacer eso, les agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Por favor añade tu código. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer eso sin usar jQuery, puedes usar el constructor de objetos:

> Intl.NumberFormat()

```js
var numero = 100000000;
    var n = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-MX').format(numero);

    console.log(n);
```

Comment: Excelente me funciono muchas gracias amigo!!

Comment: Interesante propuesta, yo no conocia este metodo, he aprendido de esto.